# Add custom Views to a View without extending layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a class that extends View and allows me to plot data. I want to make another class that extends View that contains two of these plotting views. In my particular case, I am unable to extend a layout such as LinearLayout and add views to it. My parent class has to extend View. Is it possible to build a View that consists of other custom Views without extending a layout?

Comment: You'll need to extend ViewGroup, or rework your two custom views into a single View.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer. You can create a Custom Compound View.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-compound-views-on-android--cms-22889

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it looks like this requires  you to extend a Layout instead of View. That is one of the constraints I am under because of a custom View class that I am extending.

Comment: Layouts extend `View`. Example: LinearLayout -> ViewGroup -> View -> Object